# Why bootstrap shows 2 tabs at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm developing a website with using `bootsrap v4`, and I'm struggling using `tabs`. As you may see when you click the 3rd or the last tab, and then click the first tab it shows 2 tabs at the same time and also when you keep clicking and alternating those tabs the problem goes away by it self.

What I'm doing wrong?
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/isneezy/k0uv976k/3/)

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #868e96;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-tabs>h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable>.nav-tabs li {
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable>.nav-tabs li a.active {
  background-color: #FF9F00;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable>.nav-tabs li a {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable>.nav-tabs li a.active::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FF9F00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 0;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable>.nav-tabs li a .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="//cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="search-tabs">
  <h1>Está na hora de <b><span style="" class="morphext"><span class="animated flipInX">se perder</span></span></b></h1>
  <section class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#hotels-tab" class="nav-link active"><i class="icon mdi mdi-hotel"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Hoteis</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#flights-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon fa fa-plane"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Voos</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#events-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon fa fa-bolt"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Actividades</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#rentcar-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon mdi mdi-car-hatchback"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Rent Car</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="tab-content">
      <section id="hotels-tab" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active">
        <section class="app-loading" style="min-height: 200px; display: none;"></section>
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Hoteis</h2>
          <form action="//hotels/search" method="get">
            <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
              <label>Onde vais?</label>
              <select id="destination" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
              </select>
              <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                  <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="destination-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 700px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                  <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Chegada - Saida</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Adultos </label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option value="4+">4 / +</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Crianças</label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option value="4+">4 / +</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Hoteis</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="flights-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar voos baratos</h2>
          <form action="/flights/-" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-12"><span class="trip-switch active">Ida e Volta</span> <span class="trip-switch">Só Ida</span></section>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>De onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Para onde?</label>
                  <select id="destination" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="destination-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Partida - Volta</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Adultos</label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Crianças </label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar voos</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="events-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Hoteis</h2>
          <form action="/activities//search" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-4">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-5">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Check in - Check out</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group">
                  <label>O que procura?</label>
                  <select class="form-control custom-select">
                    <option value="">Tudo</option>
                    <option value="1">Eventos</option>
                    <option value="2">Excurções</option>
                    <option value="2">Actividades</option>
                    <option value="3">Outros</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Actividades</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="rentcar-tab" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Viaturas</h2>
          <form action="/rent-car//search" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section if="hideLocation" class="col-md-4">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-8">
                <section class="row">
                  <section class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="form-group date-time-picker form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock input-icon"></i>
                      <label>Quando?</label>
                      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control flatpickr-input" value="2017-08-25 12:00" type="hidden">
                      <input class="form-control flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                    </section>
                  </section>
                  <section class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="form-group date-time-picker form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock input-icon"></i>
                      <label>Ate quanto?</label>
                      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control flatpickr-input" value="2017-09-01 12:00" type="hidden">
                      <input class="form-control flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Viaturas</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

Comment: I recommend using the full page when running the spinets

Comment: For me MacOS - Chrome is not any problems.

Comment: In MacOS - Mozilla it is!

Comment: `<li class="nav-item active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#hotels-tab" class="nav-link " aria-expanded="true">
      <i class="icon mdi mdi-hotel"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Hoteis</span></a></li>`  try this, **active** class is for li, and you have to define **area-expended="true"** in link

Comment: I found [this](https://codepen.io/jek/pen/BoWNRy) codepen, I play with Mozilla, and I click very fast and it's same problem, the view is not render in util time, so I suggest to user other plugin, make one from scratch(is not hard) and don't use css flexbox.

Comment: @AhmedSunny I've done it before but it did not work

Comment: At the end, after spending some time goggling, i found that it is a boostrap4 bug, https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23667 https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/23087

Comment: @Shiladitya 52.3.0 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution ( you may say it a work around ) https://jsfiddle.net/k0uv976k/5/

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function(){
   $($(this).data('href')).show().addClass('show active').siblings().hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Roboto, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #868e96;
  text-align: left;
}

.search-tabs > h1 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.search-tabs .tabbable > .nav-tabs li {
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.search-tabs .tabbable > .nav-tabs li a.active {
    background-color: #FF9F00;
}
.search-tabs .tabbable > .nav-tabs li a {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
}

.search-tabs .tabbable > .nav-tabs li a.active::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF9F00;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    top: -5px;
    left: 0;
}
.search-tabs .tabbable > .nav-tabs li a .icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.materialdesignicons.com/2.0.46/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="search-tabs">
  <h1>Está na hora de <b><span style="" class="morphext"><span class="animated flipInX">se perder</span></span></b></h1>
  <section class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" data-href="#hotels-tab" class="nav-link active"><i class="icon mdi mdi-hotel"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Hoteis</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" data-href="#flights-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon fa fa-plane"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Voos</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" data-href="#events-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon fa fa-bolt"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Actividades</span></a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a data-toggle="tab" data-href="#rentcar-tab" class="nav-link"><i class="icon mdi mdi-car-hatchback"></i> <span class="hidden-sm-down">Rent Car</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="tab-content">
      <section id="hotels-tab" role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade show active">
        <section class="app-loading" style="min-height: 200px; display: none;"></section>
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Hoteis</h2>
          <form action="//hotels/search" method="get">
            <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
              <label>Onde vais?</label>
              <select id="destination" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
              </select>
              <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                  <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="destination-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                </div>
                <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 700px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                  <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Chegada - Saida</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Adultos </label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option value="4+">4 / +</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Crianças</label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option value="4+">4 / +</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Hoteis</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      
      <section id="flights-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar voos baratos</h2>
          <form action="/flights/-" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-12"><span class="trip-switch active">Ida e Volta</span> <span class="trip-switch">Só Ida</span></section>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>De onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Para onde?</label>
                  <select id="destination" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full has-options" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="destination-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-6">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Partida - Volta</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Adultos</label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option selected="selected">1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-user input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Crianças </label>
                  <select class="custom-select form-control">
                    <option>0</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar voos</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="events-tab" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Hoteis</h2>
          <form action="/activities//search" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section class="col-md-4">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="fa fa-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-5">
                <section data-v-d1911898="" class="form-group range-piker">
                  <label data-v-d1911898="">Check in - Check out</label>
                  <section data-v-d1911898="" style="position: relative;">
                    <section data-v-d1911898="" class="date-range-view">
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 25 2017</section>
                      <section data-v-d1911898="" class="input"><i data-v-d1911898="" class="fa fa-calendar"></i> Ago, 28 2017</section>
                    </section>
                    <input data-v-d1911898="" class="form-control calendar-instance-input flatpickr-input" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-3">
                <section class="form-group">
                  <label>O que procura?</label>
                  <select class="form-control custom-select">
                    <option value="">Tudo</option>
                    <option value="1">Eventos</option>
                    <option value="2">Excurções</option>
                    <option value="2">Actividades</option>
                    <option value="3">Outros</option>
                  </select>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Actividades</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
      <section id="rentcar-tab" aria-expanded="false" class="tab-pane fade">
        <section>
          <h2>Pesquisar Viaturas</h2>
          <form action="/rent-car//search" method="get">
            <section class="row">
              <section if="hideLocation" class="col-md-4">
                <section class="form-group form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-map-marker input-icon"></i>
                  <label>Onde?</label>
                  <select id="origin" data-search="hotel_place" class="selectize-place selectized" tabindex="-1" style="display: none;">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="selectize-control selectize-place single">
                    <div class="selectize-input items not-full" style="">
                      <input autocomplete="off" tabindex="" id="origin-selectized" placeholder="Cidade, Hotel ou ponto de interesse" style="width: 204px;" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="selectize-dropdown single selectize-place" style="display: none; width: 100px; top: 38px; left: 0px;">
                      <div class="selectize-dropdown-content"></div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
              </section>
              <section class="col-md-8">
                <section class="row">
                  <section class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="form-group date-time-picker form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock input-icon"></i>
                      <label>Quando?</label>
                      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control flatpickr-input" value="2017-08-25 12:00" type="hidden">
                      <input class="form-control flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                    </section>
                  </section>
                  <section class="col-md-6">
                    <section class="form-group date-time-picker form-group-icon-left"><i class="mdi mdi-calendar-clock input-icon"></i>
                      <label>Ate quanto?</label>
                      <input readonly="readonly" class="form-control flatpickr-input" value="2017-09-01 12:00" type="hidden">
                      <input class="form-control flatpickr-input form-control input" placeholder="" readonly="readonly" type="text">
                    </section>
                  </section>
                </section>
              </section>
            </section>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Pesquisar Viaturas</button>
          </form>
        </section>
      </section>
    </section>
  </section>
</section>
```

I've used `jQuery` to active `tabs` and changed `href` to `data-href` in `HTML`.

**Updated answer requested by OP**

Here is the updated answer https://jsfiddle.net/k0uv976k/6/

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: @CarnaruValentin . It's working in `Firefox v54.0.1` as well as `Firefox v55.0.2` `MAC`. Please let me know your version of `Firefox`.

Comment: @Shiladitya Thanks for your answer! It helped me solving the problem. But i havd to change `data('href')` to `attr('href')` so it looks like this `$($(this).attr('href')).show().addClass('show active').siblings().hide();` it would be great if your update your answer.

Comment: @IvanVilanculo . There is a reason why I've used `data-href` and not `href`, because `href` may lead to the same problem as you were facing. I would rather recommend you to stay with `data-href`.

Comment: @Shiladitya roger that! Attention for those whom will use this workaround: the fade effect will no work as expected!

Comment: @IvanVilanculo fadeIn, slideDown, slideUp & fadeOut all will work. Her is the demo https://jsfiddle.net/k0uv976k/7/